# How to show Multiple page having same content.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, e-commerce

I am creating a simple website which basic e-commerce website.it consist of product dropdown.on which multiple products display.like this.
[image]

My question is I have to make html pages for every product?(Keeping in mind layout and everything is same just content is different).
Is there any solution i can make only single page.and display product when i click on particular category.

Comment: Where is your product information stored/located?

Comment: i have'nt store it.it is hardcoded in html

Comment: Maybe you can add a url parameter when the product is selected.  In the template hide the product content and then use jquery to show (display) content depending on the url parameter. There are probably better ways that others can suggest